# How to do htaccess redirect based on cookie value

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, redirect

I have failed at Google and I could not find the answer searching here. Sorry, I'm a newb at htaccess and it has really odd syntax and is so hard to learn!

You can see what I'm trying to do here...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*user_id=(\d+).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/mysite/cache/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/mysite/cache/guest [R=301,L]
```

I'm caching the pages for each user for load speed. I want to redirect to the proper HTML cache folder if they're logged in with a cookie, otherwise I want to load the guest cache.

Right now it goes into an infi-loop. If I remove the [R=... then I get internal server error.

Please help!!! THank you!!!

Answer (score 8):

This works for a cookie like `id=1234`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^id=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/mysite/cache/%1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/mysite/cache/guest [R=301,L]
```

Now for your problem:
Make sure that your htaccess does not apply to the page you rewrite to! For example, if your .htaccess lies in `/mysite/.htaccess`

It will be used again in

```
http://localhost/mysite/cache/%1
```

That's maybe the reason for your infinite loop. To resolve this, either make sure the htaccess rules are not applied to the sub-directories or use another directory for the cache.

Comment: Where can I look up information on how to tell it which subdirectories to apply to? Thank you.

Comment: I finally found a web page with the answer: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-tips-and-tricks.html#menu0-el14  The trick is to use a dash "-" thingy. Here is my solution that works: RewriteRule ^.+$ - [L]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for anyone else having this problem:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.+$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*user_id=(\d+).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/mysite/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/mysite/guest [R=301,L]
```

Although I haven't tested the cookie part yet - I'm sure there will be many more problems there! But the rest I tested and it works! (it goes to guest and then does not go into infi-loop, yay!)

Have a great day! 8)

Comment: thought I'd add, if you want to redirect if user_id is NOT present, do this instead: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*user_id=(\d+).*$ [NC]`