# allow from cookie htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cookies

i've a cookie named "cookiename" with value "ok", and i'm trying to make a folder work if you have that cookie

I've tryed with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^cookiename=ok$
RewriteRule .* / [NC,L]
```

without success... i'm getting redirected always

any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How to do htaccess redirect based on cookie value - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978726/how-to-do-htaccess-redirect-based-on-cookie-value

Comment: there it's no right answer there scibuff....

Comment: use `@scibuff` to notify scibuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't anchor the cookie to the start ^ or end $.   This will fail if you have multiple cookies.  It is safer to use the word-break delimiter `\b`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !\bcookiename=ok\b
```