# Redirect mobile devices example.com to example.com/m with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, subdirectory

I have 2 separate websites, 1 is the main site for large devices such as laptop & pc.

```
https://example.com/
```

My 2nd site is for all mobile devices & tablets.

```
https://example.com/m
```

I found a post [about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999615/htaccess-mobile-redirect-to-subfolder-and-desktop-view-button),

So I edited from the following creating this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/ [L,R=302]
```

but it does not solve everything. It currently takes all requests from mobile device and directs them to

```
https://example.com/m
```

How can I make the following request from mobile device,

`https://example.com/mywebpage1` => `https://example.com/m/mywebpage1`

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess ?

Comment: Yes i seen this post before making a new one, none of the following recommends that involve redirect to subdirectory with following url work. The thread is backed almost 10 years ago, Both of these websites i have are wordpress websites, and i could not get plugins to work the way i need either.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/ [L,R=302]
> ```

You are missing the `$1` backreference in the *substitution string*. It should read:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/$1 [L,R=302]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the contents of the capturing group `(.*)` in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (ie. the URL-path). Without this it will redirect everything to `/m/` as written.