# Dynamically switching language PHP,Javascript, jQuery UI

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I recently started implementing language options for my website. Here is how it basically works:

```
if(isset($_GET['lang']))
{
    $langr= $_GET['lang'];
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $langr;
    setcookie('lang', $langr, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['lang']))
{
    $langr = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
    $langr = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
    $langr = 'en';
}
switch ($langr) 
{
  case 'en':
  $lang_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/lang/en.php";
     break;
  case 'fr':
  setlocale (LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra'); 
  $lang_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/lang/fr.php";
     break;

  default:
  $lang_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/lang/en.php";

}
include_once $lang_file;
```

It loads the appropriate language file at the top of every page in my website. However, issues starting coming out when using jQuery's UI datepicker. I found a regional settings file for the datepicker online and have created a separate file for it :

```
///jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js  file

jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
        closeText: 'Fermer',
        prevText: 'Précédent',
        nextText: 'Suivant',
        currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
        monthNames: ['janvier', 'février', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin',
            'juillet', 'août', 'septembre', 'octobre', 'novembre', 'décembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['janv.', 'févr.', 'mars', 'avril', 'mai', 'juin',
            'juil.', 'août', 'sept.', 'oct.', 'nov.', 'déc.'],
        dayNames: ['dimanche', 'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['dim.', 'lun.', 'mar.', 'mer.', 'jeu.', 'ven.', 'sam.'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','L','M','M','J','V','S'],
        weekHeader: 'Sem.',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
});
```

The issue is I need to dynamically load `jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js` whenever a language change is detected so that my datepicker switches to french. What I was thinking is creating a PHP function that I would put in my `<head>` that would echo out my file, but the problem with that is that not all my web pages are PHP and I don't find this a very effective method. Any other ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Why not have javascript read the cookie and then based on that, download the correct localization file?

Comment: i think effective method can be extracting `lang cookie` information by the `datepicker.js` and loads accordingly

Comment: Hmm, loading the cookie would be an option..

Comment: Il assume making all of the pages with PHP isn't an option, your only other option is to use javascript to load the language specific files.
<hr>
Or [here is an artical on redirecting from the htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978726/how-to-do-htaccess-redirect-based-on-cookie-value). You can redirect the en file to go to the fr file based on the cookie and could also redirect based on get values! Good luck, let me know how you get on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a check in your header.php which will goes like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript>" src="/js/<?php if($_SESSION['lang'] == "en"){ echo 'datepicker-en.js'}else echo 'datepicker-fr.js'; ?>"></script>
```

So it will automatically detect the **datepicker** file according to your language parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this way, have a separate PHP file responsible for getting correct JS File, 
this way you can use it in plan HTML pages as well...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/getCorrectJsFile.php"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think of this approach?

```
function getBaseURL()
{
    var url = location.href;
    var baseURL = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/', 14));
    if (baseURL.indexOf('http://localhost') != -1)
    {
        var url = location.href; 
        var pathname = location.pathname;  
        var index1 = url.indexOf(pathname);
        var index2 = url.indexOf("/", index1 + 1);
        var baseLocalUrl = url.substr(0, index2);
        return baseLocalUrl + "/";
    }
    else
    {
        return baseURL + "/";
    }
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
   }
}


function getLang()
{
    var lang = getCookie("lang");
    switch(lang)
    {
        case "fr":
            document.write("<script src='"+getBaseURL()+"js/lang/jquery.ui.datepicker-"+lang+".js'></script>");
            break;
        default:
            document.write("");
    }
}
getLang();
```

The functions would be located in a common js file and I would call the `getLang()` function on all of my pages...

Answer (score 0):

How about using .change() and .post()? You add id of lang to your form where a user can change the language.

```
$('#lang').change(function(){
           //link to your php file
    var findlangfile = "<?php echo index.php/findlang.php;?>
    $.post(findlangfile, {
        lang: $('#lang').val(),
    }, function(response){
        // you do things
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery cookie plugin, a good one. Then do same procedure with jQuery as with php. If language supplied as url parameter - set cookie with the plugin (get language value with the getBaseURL() function above). Otherwise load cookie and then load appropriate javascript file. Something like `$('head').append('<script..');` should do the task.

Make sure to run this whole script on page load with `$(function() { /* code here */ });`

Although it's possible to accomplish the task this way, I would highly recommend switching all your pages to php, as it would simplify things like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Improved version of Moeed's answer:

---

You need to put a check in your header.php which will goes like that:

```
<script src="/js/<?php echo 'datepicker-' . *COOKIE/SESSION VALUE, LIKE en* . '.js'; ?>"></script>
```

This will dynamicly select `datepicker-???.js` where `???` is the value represented by the cookie/session-cookie.