# htaccess compare cookie value and redirect if evaluation returns true/false

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I would like somebody to help me with an if-else statement in htaccess. What I want is htaccess to read a cookie and check if its value equals a defined value. If it evaluates to false, it should excecute a redirect and prevent from the requested folder to be accessed. Maybe a deny from all would be better if the evaluation returns false.

I know that the following code checks if a named cookie value is set. If it is not set, it will execute the rewrite rule below it. But how can I adjust this line so that it checks if it equals a certain value?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*cookie_name.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com [NC,L]
```

What I would like, but in .htaccess style:

```
if ($_COOKIE['cookie_name'] != 'specific_value'){
//rewrite_rule or deny from all.
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do htaccess redirect based on cookie value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978726/how-to-do-htaccess-redirect-based-on-cookie-value)

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos. It's not a duplicate as I am actually trying to compare the values And not just simply checking if the cookie is set or not. The code of htaccess I posted already does that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're close. The cookie string needs a `=`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=specific_value; [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [NC,L]
```

Comment: For single or multiple cookies there should be pattern `;?`

If there is single Cookie present on site, the pattern will not work.

Updated solution does the job:

`RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=specific_value;? [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [NC,L]`

Comment: @Kusak and that equals to just !cookie_name=specific_value

Answer (score 8):

Replace `required_value` with the value that needs to be matched.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=required_value;? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [R=301,L]
```

`;?` makes sure that the match happens both when there are multiple cookie value pairs or when `cookie_name` is the only cookie set. This also prevents from matching on a cookie value like `off` when a match on only `of` (a substring) is required.

Comment: Yes, for single or multiple cookies there should be pattern `;?`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code that checks for specific value in the cookie:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=specific_value [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [NC,L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

The %{HTTP_COOKIE} string looks like a series of escaped name-value pairs separated by semicolons, and each semicolon is followed by a space. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie):

> Syntax
>
> ```
> Cookie: <cookie-list>
> Cookie: name=value
> Cookie: name=value; name2=value2; name3=value3
> ```
>
> <cookie-list>
>
> - A list of name-value pairs in the form of =. Pairs in the list are separated by a semicolon and a space ('; ').
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> Cookie: PHPSESSID=298zf09hf012fh2; csrftoken=u32t4o3tb3gg43; _gat=1
> ```

So in your regular expression, you need to optionally match the semicolon followed by a space at the beginning and the semicolon at the end like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} "!(?:^|; )cookie_name=specific_value(?:;|$)"
```

Note: Different set-cookie functions escape different characters. So while one function might escape the @ symbol, another one might not causing inconsistencies in how your cookie string looks. For example a search for useremail@gmail.com might fail if it is stored as useremail%40gmail.com. They are both valid.