# Apache directory listing and prevent users from accessing files without login to PHP form

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So this question has been asked but in the other questions the users want to prevent apache from listing a directory. Basically I have a website that has a login to a file exchange system, if the user is logged in then he can get access to content that is uploaded by other users. Here is how I prevent users from accessing certain parts of my site

```
function loggedin()
{
 if (isset($_SESSION['myusername']) || isset($_COOKIE['myusername']))
 {
        return true;
 }
else {
            return false;
     }
}
```

I use this code to show all directories in my uploads folder:

```
<?php
$dir = "./uploads";
$list = scandir($dir); /* This function sorts dirs */
$list = array_diff($list,array(".","..","index.php"));

echo "<ol>";
foreach ($list as $file)
{
   if (!is_dir($file)) echo "<li><a href='https://rye-high.ca/Rye High/$dir/$file'>$file</a></li>\n";
}
echo "</ol>";
?>
```

NOW for sheer simplicity I allow apache to list the directories using `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` because I like how apache does it automatically and prevents me from coding something that might break in php.

My Question: Users that know the filename/folder name can access the files (and directory) directly without logging into the system (i.e. mysite.ca/Rye High/uploads/ACC 100/. I would like to prevent this by still keeping Option Indexes turned on so that apache can list the files to users who are actually logged in.

How can it be done? .htaccess file?

I considered editing the default apache template code for listing directories however I may not want this for other virtual hosts (globally) in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use apache's Basic Auth module ( http://linuxzoo.net/page/tut_authapache.html ) and further you can generate .htpasswd files using PHP - http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/create-password-for-htpasswd-file-using-php/.

A good way is to use something like php file manager:

- https://github.com/adrian7/phpfilebrowser
- http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/
- http://encode-explorer.siineiolekala.net/

Or you could set a cookie after the user successfully signs in, and then check the cookie in a htaccess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382160/htaccess-compare-cookie-value-and-redirect-if-evaluation-returns-true-false .
The issue with this, is that somebody who knows the cookie value will be able to browse your files without signing in in the first place.

Comment: So I would have to create a new .htpasswd file for each user? and how would I connect the .htpasswd file to my mysql database and $_SESSION data? I have 1000's of users so this would be inefficient. Also the parameters of my question said that I want to keep the current apache directory listing NOT substitute it for an PHP file browser.

Comment: Ther's a slight unconsistenty in your question. You say you want to authenticate users with php but still allow them to browse folders on your server, without reaching any php script. While is possible to implement that, in a weird and unpleaseant way using a proxy server or cURL, you should know the PHP Session it's not available to apache itself - only to PHP.

Comment: So either you pass requests through PHP and check user authentication, either you move the authentication process to a higher layer of your application, which in your case it seems to be the server.

Comment: how would you do this using PHP in this case while still keeping option indexes turned on? would I have to add a php authentication file to each directory inside the uploads directory?

Comment: essentially I would like an option that authenticates using PHP BUT keeps apache indexes on so that apache can list the directory and NOT PHP