# Set headers in .htaccess from COOKIE

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies, request-headers

I need to do such thing in htaccess:
Check if "auth_key" COOKIE exists (I will set it in frontend part)
And then add this value to headers

And also my url is also with rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/files/content
RewriteRule api/(.*)$ /server/api/web/$1 [NC,L]
```

I don't understand how to add to this rule also headers with COOKIE value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382160/htaccess-compare-cookie-value-and-redirect-if-evaluation-returns-true-false shows how you can access cookie values. What you do with them is up to you

Comment: @apokryfos - the problem is that I don't understand what alias I will use. So if my rewrite url is added by $1, then what will be cookie value

Comment: `$1` signifies a regular expression match. In your provided example you have `api/(.*)` so `$1` will be whatever matched within `(.*)` (i.e. everything after the `api/`)

Comment: @apokryfos - yes, that I understand. Then I add something like RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^auth_key=(.*)$, and set headers - Header add Strict-Transport-Security "Authorization=?????" - how to push got cookie value to "???" ?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^auth_key=(.*)$` then next line `RewriteRule  set headers - Header add Strict-Transport-Security "Authorization=%1` might work I think %1 will refer to the previous line match. Not sure haven't done that in a while, you should check.

Comment: What header do you want to set for the given cookie value?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way, you can parse cookie value and set a custom header:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|\s)auth_key=[^;]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=COOKIE_AUTH_VAL:%1]

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "%{COOKIE_AUTH_VAL}e"
```