# .htaccess Compare Cookie with data from file/link

Tags: .htaccess, authentication, cookies

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382160/htaccess-compare-cookie-value-and-redirect-if-evaluation-returns-true-false) answer, I know I can check if a cookie has a value with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=specific_value; [NC]
```

But I would like `specific_value` to be an list of values pulled from a file/link. Heres what I mean in a mix of .htacess and PHP

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=file_get_contents("mycookielist.txt"); [NC]
```

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=file_get_contents("http://example.com/mycookielist.txt"; [NC]
```

Comment: "I can check if a cookie has a value with..." - that bit of code checks that the cookie does **not** have a value. You can't do something like this in `.htaccess` alone. If you have access to the main server-config then maybe you can create a _rewrite map_ (which can consist of a simple text file), and have `.htaccess` lookup the value from this _rewrite map_?

Comment: @DocRoot I edited it. I do have access (I host everything myself) could you potentially help write a rewrite map.