# how to use .htaccess with variables from RewriteCond and RewriteRule at the same time

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

1. > I have a htaccess code that redirects all the requests from
   >   /forum1/product to /product. The code in /forum1/product/.htaccess is as follows:
   >
   > ```
   > <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   > RewriteEngine On
   > RewriteBase /
   > RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /product/$1 [PT,L]
   > </IfModule>
   > ```
   >
   > This code works perfectly for "/forum1/product/", "/forum2/product/",
   >   "forum3/product/",... etc. so all my forums are using the same product
   >   code(also I have used $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in product code so
   >   that product responds distinctly for each forum).

2.

> I have a new version of product which I don't want to make live yet.
>   So am trying to set a cookie "version" and based on the version it
>   should redirect to corresponding product_<version number> folder by
>   referring:
>   [How to do htaccess redirect based on cookie value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978726/how-to-do-htaccess-redirect-based-on-cookie-value)
>
> ```
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^version=([0-9]*)$ [NC] 
>   RewriteRule .* http://localhost/product_%1/ [R=301,L]
>   RewriteRule .* http://local-host/product/ [R=301,L]
> ```

Both 1 and 2 works fine seperately. I want to merge these two conditions.

So if cookie "version" is set to 2 then /forum/product redirects to /product_2 but still shows the URL /forum/product but it will be using /product_2

The folder structure is as follows:

```
/forum1/product/.htaccess
/forum2/product/.htaccess
/forum3/product/.htaccess
/product/version.txt
/product_1/version.txt
/product_2/version.txt
```

I think the following code should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^version=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /product_%1/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /product/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218164/multiple-rewriterules-for-single-rewritecond-in-htaccess

Comment: And `RewriteCond` variables are `%1+` while `RewriteRule` variables are `$1+`. So you can easily combine them in the same `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It took some time, but finally I got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^version=([0-9]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /product_%1/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /product/$1 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} version=([0-9]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /product_%1/ [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /product/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The folder structure is:<br />
/forum1/product/.htaccess<br />
/forum2/product/.htaccess<br />
/forum3/product/.htaccess<br />
/product/version.txt<br />
/product_1/version.txt<br />
/product_2/version.txt<br />

if "cookie version" is set to 1 then http://localhost/forum1/product/version.txt should show 1

Comment: I am confused about `version.txt` now as you didn't mention this in your question. Can you edit the question and clarify bit more.