# Redirect on cookie, use htaccess or php, what's faster

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, cookies

I want to redirect visitors to a certain page depending on if they have a cookie set or not. Would it be better to do this in PHP or htaccess? I'm a complete noob when it comes to htaccess but I feel like there would be an obvious speed advantage because it actually happens before the site is loaded, while the php happens after, am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978726/how-to-do-htaccess-redirect-based-on-cookie-value for information about redirecting based on a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the difference is probably negligible, but since the directives in the htaccess file is cached (would be even faster if you put rules in your server/vhost config), there isn't a need to hand the request off to a handler (like php).

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookiename=cookievalue
RewriteRule ^(?!certain-page.php) /certain-page.php [L,R]
```